# Moving one leg moves the rest of the armature

Tags: rigging, bones

https://gfycat.com/ContentLividBullmastiff

I did a simple rig following a tutorial but when i want to move its legs using ik, every time the thigh moves, the whole body follows, i already checked the weighs and that is not the problem, any idea what could it be?

P.S: The problem is solved when I un-parent the thighs from the hips, but I cant leave it that way...

Comment: Hi tacofisher welcome to Blender SE.  What's the length of the IK chain constraint set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does changing the chain length fix it?
In the Properties Editor->Constraints->IK

https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/tracking/ik_solver.html

Comment: that fixed it, i had it set to 0 so it moved all bones but changing it to 2 fixed the problem, thanks!